# Remote (Workbench) access to Openshift V3 database

Tags: openshift, mysql-workbench

My project is a J2EE+MySQL application. In Openshift v2 environment, I relied on a mySQL workbench to manage the database via ssh connections. Now, I am migrating this app to Openshift V3.

I would like to remotely manage the database (is it a pod in V3?) from a workbench rather than doing "oc rsh database-pod". Is this possible? What would be the best-practice for managing databases remotely in Openshift V3?

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the blog post:

- https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-connecting-database-using-port-forwarding/

and you can work through an interactive tutorial (Connecting to a Database Using Port Forwarding) on the issue at:

- https://learn.openshift.com/